# Extending Asp.net CompareValidator

Tags: asp.net, validation

How to extend a compareValidator so i can check, if user has written some text in ControlToValidate then he must write some text in ControlToCompare too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
public class ExtendedCompareValidator : CompareValidator
{

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ControlToValidate) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ControlToCompare))
            throw new HttpException("You have to set the 'ControlToCompare' property.");

        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }

}
```

**Web.Config**

```
<pages>
  <tagMapping>
    <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompareValidator, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" mappedTagType="MyWebApp.ExtendedCompareValidator, MyWebApp"/>
  </tagMapping>
</pages>
```

Comment: How i will use this validator? <asp:ExtendedCompareValidator>?

Comment: You don't need to change anything. Use traditional `CompareValidator` control and ASP.NET maps it with new one.

Comment: No its not working. It has the same behavior as of normal CompareValidator control.

Comment: Did you add the above code snippet to the `pages` section of web.config? Also don't forgot to change the `mappedTagType` property.

Comment: <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompareValidator, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" mappedTagType="CustomValidators.ExtendCompareValidator, App_Code"/>

Comment: `<add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompareValidator, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" mappedTagType="MyWebApp.ExtendedCompareValidator"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to extend `CompareValidator` to solve this. Use `RequiredFieldValidator` on both controls to validate they are not empty. This approach have the advantage of validating on the client side as well so avoiding a round trip to server.